# Jquery append Stripe pay button returns [object HTMLScriptElement]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to append the Stripe pay with card button via jquery. I'm appending it because I want it to be displayed once the user meets a certain requirement, and because the price is variable.

I have this code so far

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
                            script.src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
                            script.class="stripe-button";
                            $(script).prop({"data-key" : "pk_test_gJIeYpuvZc56uI22j5yr7h3s", "data-amount" : '"' + amount_paid + '"', "data-name" : "website.com", "data-description" : '"' + purch_item + ' ($'+ final_value +')"', "data-image" : "image.png"});
$('.payment_stripe_span').append('<form action="make_payment.php" method="POST">' + script + '</form>');
```

However, this prints [object HTMLScriptElement].

How do I make the button appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an object as a string. Here is your solution.

Here is modified code. I used javascript's setAttribute method.

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
var amount_paid = 10;
var purch_item = 'Test';
var final_value = 15;

script.src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";

script.setAttribute("class", "stripe-button");
script.setAttribute("data-key", "pk_test_gJIeYpuvZc56uI22j5yr7h3s");
script.setAttribute("data-amount", amount_paid);
script.setAttribute("data-name", "website.com");
script.setAttribute("data-description", '"' + purch_item + ' ($'+ final_value +')"');
script.setAttribute("data-image", "image.png");

$('.payment_stripe_span').append('<form action="make_payment.php" method="POST" id="my_frm">Form ( Inspect here to check if the DOM is added or not? )</form>');

$(script).appendTo("#my_frm");
```

Link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kzfkuv3m/3/

Comment: The script tag shows up. However, the actual button doesn't appear.

Comment: Go with updated code and you have your solution. It is working fine on jsfiddle